# Certificate Signing Request - relevance of CN for code signing

Tags: ssl-certificate, code-signing-certificate

Generating a CSR needs the server-name, organization, country etc. The server-name is used in SSL to make sure the server you are talking to is the server which was certified. **Question is `(1)`** what is the relevance of server-name if I use a certificate for code-signing?

Code signing certificates are different from SSL certificate only in flags. Rest is all the same. Now if I take a SSL certificate issued to foo.com and install it on bar.com then it wont work. What about code signing certificate? If a take a code signing certificate issued to foo.com and install it on bar.com and sign DLLs or JARs from there, then would there be any problem **`(2)`?**

I guess there should not be any. I do not have such a certificate so I cant test it, but by theory should there be any problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the relevance of server-name if I use a certificate for code-signing?

there are no dependencies. However, proper subject field will help to identify the original publisher.

> then would there be any problem

no. There is no other subject name to compare. For code signing certificates, subject may be any, it must be just descriptive.